# php mysql sort by date (Recent)

Tags: php, android, mysql, sql, api

I have now my code is fetching data in mobile application from SQL as first added showing first, I need to set it as showing last added as first in my android application. I have api code like below, in latest its showing as per my requirement but for cid and aid I need same as latest ( must show recent as first). My code is like below
Thanks

```
<?php include("includes/connection.php");

error_reporting(0);

mysql_query("SET NAMES 'utf8'");    

if(isset($_GET['cid']))
{
if(isset($_GET['cat_id']))
{

    $cat_id=$_GET['cat_id'];        

        $query="SELECT * FROM tbl_quotes
    LEFT JOIN tbl_category ON tbl_quotes.cat_id= tbl_category.cid 
    where tbl_quotes.cat_id='".$cat_id."'";

}
else if(isset($_GET['latest']))
{
    $limit=$_GET['latest'];     
    $query="SELECT * FROM tbl_quotes
    LEFT JOIN tbl_category ON tbl_quotes.cat_id= tbl_category.cid 
    ORDER BY tbl_quotes.id DESC LIMIT $limit";
}
else
{

    $query="SELECT cid,category_name,category_image FROM tbl_category";


}
$resouter = mysql_query($query);

$set = array();

$total_records = mysql_num_rows($resouter);
if($total_records >= 1){

  while ($link = mysql_fetch_array($resouter, MYSQL_ASSOC)){

    $set['Quotes'][] = $link;

  }
}

    /* output in format */

 //echo $val= str_replace('\\/', '/', json_encode($set));
     header( 'Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8' );

    echo str_replace('\\/', '/',json_encode($set,JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE));


    }
else{
if(isset($_GET['aid']))
{

    $author_id=$_GET['aid'];        

        $qry="SELECT * FROM tbl_quotes
    LEFT JOIN tbl_author ON tbl_quotes.aid= tbl_author.author_id 
    where tbl_quotes.aid='".$author_id."'";

}
else if(isset($_GET['latest']))
{
    $limit=$_GET['latest'];     
    $qry="SELECT * FROM tbl_quotes
    LEFT JOIN tbl_author ON tbl_quotes.aid= tbl_author.author_id
    LEFT JOIN tbl_category ON tbl_quotes.cat_id= tbl_category.cid
    ORDER BY tbl_quotes.id DESC LIMIT $limit";
}
else
{

    $qry="SELECT author_id,author_name,author_image FROM tbl_author";

}

$resultouter = mysql_query($qry);

$author_set = array();

$total_records = mysql_num_rows($resultouter);
if($total_records >= 1){

  while ($link = mysql_fetch_array($resultouter, MYSQL_ASSOC)){

    $author_set['Quotes'][] = $link;
  }
}

// echo $value= str_replace('\\/', '/', json_encode($author_set));

    /* output in format */

    header( 'Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8' );

    echo str_replace('\\/', '/',json_encode($author_set,JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE));
}
?>
```

Comment: you want even date to be ordered with the id??

Comment: Be aware that the old mysql_* extension which you're using is deprecated in version 5.5 of PHP (the current version) and is being removed from version 7 (the next version). You need migrate over to using either the mysqli_* extension or PDO
 
You're a sitting duck for SQL Injection attacks with that code as no validation of the user submitted data takes place and it isn't even escaped!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use the `SELECT` statement to query data from a table, the result set is not sorted in any orders. To sort the result set, you use the `ORDER BY`

like that :-

```
ORDER BY column1 [ASC|DESC]
```

in your code :-

```
$query="SELECT * FROM tbl_quotes
    LEFT JOIN tbl_category ON tbl_quotes.cat_id= tbl_category.cid 
    ORDER BY tbl_quotes.id DESC,date DESC LIMIT $limit";
```

if you column data type is not `date` or `datetime` us `cast()` like that :-

```
CAST(column_name AS DATETIME);
CAST(column_name AS DATE);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use order by for date as well.

```
 ORDER BY tbl_quotes.id DESC, DATE(your_date_column) desc
```

Also see this [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/order-by-optimization.html) for more information