# php mysql sort by DESC

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have api code like below, in latest its showing as per my requirement but for cid and aid I need same as latest ( must show recent as first). My code is like below Thanks

```
<?php include("includes/connection.php");

mysql_query("SET NAMES 'utf8'");

if(isset($_GET['language_id']))
{ 
    $query="SELECT cid,category_name,category_image FROM tbl_category WHERE lid='".$_GET['language_id']."'";

}
else if(isset($_GET['cat_id']))
{

    $cat_id=$_GET['cat_id'];        

        $query="SELECT * FROM tbl_quotes
    LEFT JOIN tbl_category ON tbl_quotes.cat_id= tbl_category.cid 
    where tbl_quotes.cat_id='".$cat_id."'";

}
else if(isset($_GET['latest']))
{
    $limit=$_GET['latest'];     
    $query="SELECT * FROM tbl_quotes
    LEFT JOIN tbl_category ON tbl_quotes.cat_id= tbl_category.cid 
    ORDER BY tbl_quotes.id DESC LIMIT $limit";
}
else if(isset($_GET['home_banner']))
{

    $query="SELECT app_name,app_url,app_image FROM tbl_banner";     

}
else if(isset($_GET['about_app']))
{

    $query="SELECT app_name,app_logo,app_email,app_website,app_description FROM tbl_settings";      

}
else
{

    $query="SELECT id,language_name FROM tbl_language";


}
$resouter = mysql_query($query);

$set = array();

$total_records = mysql_num_rows($resouter);
if($total_records >= 1){

  while ($link = mysql_fetch_array($resouter, MYSQL_ASSOC)){

    $set['Quotes'][] = $link;
  }
}
else
{
    $set['Quotes'][] = null;
}
 header( 'Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8' );
 echo $val= str_replace('\\/', '/', json_encode($set));
```

Experimented amendment to this but to no avail

```
else if(isset($_GET['cat_id']))
{

    $cat_id=$_GET['cat_id'];        

        $query="SELECT * FROM tbl_quotes
    LEFT JOIN tbl_category ON tbl_quotes.cat_id= tbl_category.cid 
    where tbl_quotes.cat_id='".$cat_id."'";

}
```

Try this also did it succeed [php mysql sort by date (Recent)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33447927/php-mysql-sort-by-date-recent)

This is the link api `/api.php?cat_id=1`

Comment: Use like this $query="SELECT cid,category_name,category_image FROM tbl_category WHERE lid='".$_GET['language_id']."' order by cid DESC";

Comment: mysql-* is deprecated try to use mysqli_*

Answer (score 2):

When you use the **SELECT statement** to query data from a table, the result set is not sorted in any orders. To sort the result set, you use the **ORDER BY**

like that :-

```
ORDER BY column1 [ASC|DESC]
```

Like Below change the code according to it:-

```
$query="SELECT * FROM tbl_quotes
    LEFT JOIN tbl_category ON tbl_quotes.cat_id= tbl_category.cid 
    ORDER BY tbl_quotes.id DESC,date DESC LIMIT $limit";
```

Answer (score 0):

thanx for all
I've tried this and succeeded

```
else if(isset($_GET['cat_id']))


$cat_id=$_GET['cat_id'];        

    $query="SELECT * FROM tbl_quotes
LEFT JOIN tbl_category ON tbl_quotes.cat_id= tbl_category.cid 
where tbl_quotes.cat_id='".$cat_id."' order by cid DESC";
```